# Change the default form in created contacts in Outlook

Tags: forms, vba, outlook, default

You know that Outlook has a default form to show contacts(this one)[image]

and I have my own form created(this one)[image]

I want to see all my contacts like my own form,but I only can create new contacts with that form.I can't modify the created ones,which are with the default form.
How can I do that?
Could I do it with a macro?Any idea?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Forms are associated with the message class. You need to change the [MessageClass](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867813(v=office.15).aspx) property values for contacts where you want to get the form shown. For example, when an item is selected, Outlook uses the message class to locate the form and expose its properties.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.Could you give me an example?
I don't know a lot of Outlook...
Thanks